# When does "Determining if ip address x.x.x.y is already in use" apply

Tags: networking, centos, centos6, ifconfig

I've just setup a couple of C-Class IPs on different servers and I noticed after adding the `ifcfg-eth0-range0` script and restarting the network interface I always get messages like

```
Determining if ip address x.x.x.y is already in use for device eth0...
```

The thing I'm questioning now is that the y value is always something different. I'm always adding x.x.x.2 - x.x.x.254 to one server.

on one server it's

```
Determining if ip address x.x.x.17 is already in use for device eth0...
Determining if ip address x.x.x.18 is already in use for device eth0...
...
Determining if ip address x.x.x.254 is already in use for device eth0...
```

and on another it starts with a higher number

```
Determining if ip address x.x.x.171 is already in use for device eth0...
Determining if ip address x.x.x.171 is already in use for device eth0...
...
Determining if ip address x.x.x.254 is already in use for device eth0...
```

I know this can be altered by adding `ARPCHECK=no` but what interests me is what determins the value of which this check starts and why does it lead to those different results?

Comment: Classful addressing went away 20 years ago...do you mean "IP addresses in a /24 subnet"?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant